# Share ALAsset fullResolutionImage with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, share, assets

It doesn't seem it is possible to embed a full resolution asset in an email. It works well if I use the fullScreenImage representation. I guess there should be some limits in image size but I couldn't find any information about it. I am on an iPhone 4S and the full resolution image is 2448 by 3264 px.

Code:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [_asset defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef imageRef = [assetRepresentation fullResolutionImage];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:[assetRepresentation scale] orientation:[assetRepresentation orientation]];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[img] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is the following... instead of adding the fullResolutionImage to the array of data to share, add the actual asset itself.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]    initWithActivityItems:@[_asset] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

where _asset is the ALAsset instance of your image.